# How do I encrypt a Hibernate Configuration File

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration

Hibernate has configuration file where we provide database access credentials which it uses to connect to the database. If someone gets hold of the config file, he can completely crash the system.

Is there any way, where we can only secure confidential information from the config file. I do not want the programming team to do access the database.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `Jasypt` to encrypt the config file data

http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html